# TypeScript generics and union function types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a record type that allows me to assign a string key but different function types.  So far, I have tried a few different things and the compiler and I just don't agree.  Here is the code I have so far.

```
interface MyAFunctionType {
  (): { type: string };
}

interface MyBFunctionType<B> {
  (b?: B): { type: string, key?: B | undefined };
}

interface MyCFunctionType<C> {
  (c?: C): { type: string, param?: C | undefined };
}

function MyAFunction(): MyAFunctionType {
    return function() {
        return {
            type: 'hello'
        }
    }
}

function MyBFunction<B>(): MyBFunctionType<B> {
    return function(key?: B | undefined) {
        if (typeof key === 'undefined') {
            return {
                key,
                type: 'hello'
            }
        }

        return {
            key,
            type: 'hello'
        }
    }
}

function MyCFunction<C>(): MyCFunctionType<C> {
    return function(key?: C | undefined) {
        if (typeof key === 'undefined') {
            return {
                key,
                type: 'hello'
            }
        }

        return {
            key,
            type: 'hello'
        }
    }
}

type MyFunctionUnion<B, C> = MyAFunctionType | MyBFunctionType<B> | MyCFunctionType<C>;

function MyRecordFunction<B, C>() {
    const records: Record<string, MyFunctionUnion<B, C>> = {};

    records['a'] = MyAFunction();
    records['b'] = MyBFunction();
    records['c'] = MyCFunction();

    return records;
}

interface MyBInterface {
    foo: 'bar'
}

interface MyCInterface {
    baz: 'bus'
}

const myRecords = MyRecordFunction<MyBInterface, MyCInterface>();

myRecords.a();
myRecords.b({ foo: 'bar' });
myRecords.c({ baz: 'bas '});
```

The compiler gives me the following error when passing the arguments to `myRecords.b` and `myRecords.c`

```
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.(2554)
```

I am not too sure what it's trying to tell me.  To me this seems like it should work.  This looks to be an issue with actually assigning the functions with the intersection type... It doesn't like that I am trying to assign two different types of functions here.

My question is how can I assign different function types in this way with a `Record` if I have many different signatures I want to assign?  Is this even possible?

Comment: `MyAFunction<A> & MyBFunction<B>` is not a union, it's intersection, did you mean `MyAFunction<A> | MyBFunction<B>`?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova That crossed my mind but even when I change it from an intersection to a union I get the following `Argument of type '"a-type"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.(2345)`

Comment: `r.something('a-type');` on this line? where do you define `something`?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Correct -- `something` is being defined in the function in the `Record`

Comment: `SomeFunction<'a-type', 'b-type'>();` - these have to be actual types, like `SomeFunction<string, string>();`, not string literals

Comment: I'm trying to see a coherent use case here and I'm failing. `MyAFunction` and `MyBFunction` are equivalent to each other; you might as well just use, say, `MyFunction`. Then, an intersection of function types means that each property has to act as *both* `MyFunction<A>` *and* a `MyFunction<B>`. Since that's not what you're doing, you must mean the union instead.  But a union of two function types is hard/impossible to actually discriminate. Are you expecting the compiler to remember that the `something` method is of type `MyFunction<A>`, even though the call signature is just a `Record` type?

Comment: Oh, and what purpose do the functions named `MyAFunction` and `MyBFunction` serve?  You don't seem to be calling them anywhere.  And those are equivalent functions, also, in the way that `x => x + 3` and `y => y + 3` are equivalent... but you go through the trouble of defining both of them.  I'm confused; help!

Comment: @jcalz Basically the use case is to be able to have an object of keys that each have different functions that can be called at a later time.

Comment: @jcalz Oh, the functions have to be able to take different implementations in the form of optional parameters

Comment: "an object of keys that each have different functions that can be called at a later time"... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weeO1w)?  If not, could you carefully explain the use case?  The type `{something: MyFunction<A>, "something-else": MyFunction<B>}` is like a spice cabinet with salt and sugar sitting next to each other.  If you call that `Record<string, MyFunction<A> | MyFunction<B>`, you are pouring the salt and the sugar onto your countertop and mixing them together.  If you want to be able to use the salt and sugar separately, you shouldn't mix them together in the first place.

Comment: "Oh, the functions have to be able to take different implementations in the form of optional parameters" <-- I'm not understanding this.  Your `MyAFunction` and `MyBFunction` functions are identical to each other.  Your `MyAFunction` and `MyBFunction` types are identical to each other. Differently named parameters or generic type parameters don't make different functions or types.  And your `MyAFunction` and `MyBFunction` functions are unused in your example code.

Comment: @jcalz You're close with your code here, but I need it to be added to a record of some sort for later.  The `MyAFunction` and `MyBFunction` were supposed to serve the purpose of showing that these functions can be slightly different (I obviously failed).  Because all of the functions have different return types, they aren't all the same.

Comment: "I need it to be added to a record of some sort for later".  Do you?  Can you show a use case with code that demonstrates a need for this?  Is the record coming from inside of `SomeFunction` or from outside?  If it's coming from inside, why does it matter if it's being added one property at a time or all at once?  If it's coming from outside, the example code doesn't motivate it and you should edit it, maybe to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGngKm)?

Comment: @jcalz `Record<keyof R, MyFunction<A> | MyFunction<B>>` This is what I would expect would work in my code, but for some reason it doesn't if I do a union of anything else that isn't `MyFunction` ... This is where my confusion lies really

Comment: " but for some reason it doesn't if I do a union of anything else that isn't `MyFunction`"  Can you show me this with code instead of just using words?

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question and you can find the code [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgr19W)

Comment: My question is still: why are you trying to use a `Record` when such a type is not suitable?  What about [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6Z6N) fails to meet your use case?  Ideally you'll either say "yes, this type works for me", or "no, this type doesn't work because I can't do *this*" where you provide a link to code that only works properly with a `Record`.   I'm not sure if you understood my silly analogy about mixing salt and sugar together and then being sad when you can't use them separately.

Comment: @jcalz In my case the keys are dynamically created, thus leaving me to use brackets to assign the values to keys -- if there is a more appropriate type than `Record` I am all ears

Comment: Sorry, I think we're at an impasse; you've mentioned several times that keys are dynamically created, but I don't see that happening in your code.  All your code has functions with string literal keys like `"a"` that could be statically represented in object types, without reference to anything like `Record`.  If you ever do modify the example code to a version where statically known keys are not present, let me know.  Good luck to you!